# How to convert .pgm file to .mat file in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, mat, pgm

I have to convert 'Yale' dataset whose format is `.pgm` to `.mat` file, I searched about this issue but couldn't find anything.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried using `imwrite()`?

Comment: @AmitSingh How to write it? can you help me?

Comment: Read your .pgm image using `imread('your-pgm-image')` and then write it using `imwrite(variable-you-read-into,'output-file-name')`.

Comment: @AmitSingh I run this code: A=imread('yale2.pgm') /n imwrite(A,'YaleB',mat), error says 'mat' is undefind variable, becuase 'mat' is not supported extension by imwrite().

Comment: You should try writing `imwrite(A,'YaleB.mat')`

Comment: @AmitSingh thank u,but It's not correct. do you have any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images can be saved in `.mat` format by using the `save()` function offered by MATLAB.

Let us suppose the name of your image is `xyz.pgm` that has to be saved as `xyz.mat`. Following steps should do so :

```
im = imread('xyz.pgm')
save('xyz.mat','im')
```

You can look into [`save()`](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) function to learn more about it.

Instead if you just want to convert it into other image formats, you should look up [`imwrite()`](http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/techdoc/ref/imwrite.html).

Comment: thank u, just one question: if I have 4 .pgm images and want to save them in a uniqe .mat file , in that occassion what should I do? for example, PIE.mat file consists of many images. I want to put all of 4 images in just one .mat file.

Comment: You can use `('xyz.mat','im1','im2','im3','im4','im5')` where `im<n>` represent ith image variable.